# Bluetooth still active after app killed using react native

Tags: react-native, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, ios-bluetooth

I have a problem with the lifecycle of Bluetooth on iOS.
We are using React Native and the following library (https://github.com/innoveit/react-native-ble-manager) to manage our Bluetooth devices.

The devices sends data and clears its local data when it has sent all its data through bluetooth (we are only using ble messages ACK, no internal app ACK).

The problem is, that iOS seems to maintain the ble open when the app is killed, which is making the device think that it is still sending data that is processed correctly by our app, and clears it at the end (which causes data loss).

Is this a normal behaviour on iOS ? (the fact that the ble stays open for some time after the app is killed, and no errors are sent through ble ?)

Is there a way to force close the ble when the app is killed ?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is this a normal behaviour on iOS ? (the fact that the ble stays open for some time after the app is killed, and no errors are sent through ble ?)

Yes, this is normal. The OS holds open the connection and shares it with apps. The apps do not hold connections directly. It can take some time (generally on the order of seconds, but sometimes a bit longer) for the OS to drop the connection after the last app releases it.

> Is there a way to force close the ble when the app is killed ?

No. There is no way to do anything when the app is killed (by which I assume you for force-quit, for example by swiping up on the app switcher).

All that said, I'm a bit surprised here that you're getting a write response back to the device if the app is no longer reading. When you say "ble messages ACK," specifically which "ack" do you mean? Are you getting a Write Response packet back? Or do you mean a lower-level ack?

Comment: I was meaning a low-level ACK (I assume a Bluetooth message ACK?), we have no ACK on the app part currently and it needs more work on the device to be added (and more time)  

So our device, currently, checks if the messages are correctly sent via the Ble ACK  
And it assumes that, when all the data blocks he sent are ACKed by Bluetooth, it can continue its actions

Comment: You'll need to better explain your setup. Does your device advertise a characteristic that it expects the phone to read? Does it use notifications or indications to alert the phone? Or does the phone advertise a characteristic that the device writes to? Does it write with requests or commands? I don't know what "Bluetooth message ACK" means. There are many different ACKs in Bluetooth, and some connections are reliable and others are unreliable.

Comment: I assume this is setup with the device as the peripheral, and maybe it's using notify (in which case there's no response) and maybe it's using indicate (and then iOS may be sending the response automatically when then OS receives it the value, even if nothing is currently subscribed, which makes sense). If you need this to be reliable without app-level ACKs, then you'd likely need to turn it around so that the phone acts as the peripheral, and the device acts as the central. That will let you send WriteResponse when you've completely processed the write.

Comment: Do note that even if iOS automatically killed the connection when you were quit, it wouldn't fix this problem. Unless your software is involved in sending the ACK when it's completely done, you can't ensure a fully reliable connection. For example, your app could be force quit between the time that you received the delegate callback and the time you actually process the data. The current situation is just making it a bit more obvious that there is a race condition.

Comment: In my understanding of the device part, they must have a way to be reliable using Bluetooth for each messages, because we do not make any ACKs on the app part, but they are able to know when we lost a packet.
For the usage part, we are syncking blocks of data, the app knows in advance the number of blocks that it will receive, the device sends them one by one. But, and there was the problem: if the app is closed or has an error during the reception, the device will still continue to send its data unless the Ble connection is closed, and when it finishes, it clear its local data, so currently,

Comment: we are loosing data because of the fact that iOS dont close the connection when the app is killed.
But we found a temporary workaround right now (forcing the background processing on iOS) until we implement the device ACK part to avoid loosing the data.

Thanks for your answers, it was very interresting to learn about how iOS manages ble connections lifecycle!